# How to close all items when I open one

Tags: javascript, jquery

to be brief, am looking for a way to close all the items in the header when I click on one.
This is my js code :

```
  var menuItems = $('.menu li.item-child');
  menuItems.each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var activatingA = $this.find('>a');
    var btn = '<button><span><span class="visuallyhidden">show submenu for “' +
      activatingA.text() + '”</span></span></button>';
    $this.append(btn);

    $this.find("button").click(function(event) {
      event.preventDefault();
      $(this).parents('li.item-child').toggleClass("open");
      $(this).attr('aria-expanded', function(index, attr) {
        return attr == 'true' ? 'false' : 'true';
      });
    });


    $(".navbar-toggler").click(function (event) {
      $('body').toggleClass("overlay");
    });

    $(".navbar-close").click(function () {
      $('.menu-syno').removeClass("show");
      $('.navbar-toggler').attr("aria-expanded", 'false');
      $('body').removeClass("overlay");
    });
  });
```

Here is a screenshot too:
[image]

Comment: Call `$('.menu-syno').removeClass("show");` on button click? Or move close action to separate function and call it

Comment: it's not working :(

Comment: jq is command line JSON parser not jquery (removing tag)